# flutter: firebase messaging navigator not working

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I have an issue implementing firebase messaging.

When application in foreground notification data printed in debug log, but navigator not working.
When application in background and notification had tapped, notification data printed in debug log but navigator is not working.

Here's my code

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initiateData();
  }

  initiateData() async{
    firebase = new FirebaseMessaging();
    firebase.configure(
      onLaunch: (message){
        Log.write("on launch fcm");

      },

      onMessage: (message){
        Log.write("on message fcm");
        Log.write(json.encode(message));


        TanamDuitNavigator.present(context,
          child: new FullWebPages(
            language: "id",
            url: "https://example.com",
          )
        );
      },
      onResume: (message){
        Log.write("on resume fcm");
      }
    );
    firebase.requestNotificationPermissions();
    firebase.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen(
      (IosNotificationSettings setting){
        Log.write("Setting registered : $setting");
      });
    firebase.getToken().then((token){
      Log.write("fcm token : "+token);
      TanamStore.saveFcmToken(token);
    }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  }
```

here it's what actually TanamduitNavigator presenting

```
static Future<dynamic> present(BuildContext context,
    {bool opq = false,
     Widget child,
     Widget curPage,
     Color barrier = ColorCollections.blackBarrier
    }
  ){
    return Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(
      opaque: opq,
      pageBuilder: (_,Animation<double> animation,__){
        return child;
      },
      barrierColor: barrier,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      transitionsBuilder: (_,Animation<double>animation,__,Widget child){
        return new FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: new SlideTransition(
            position: new Tween<Offset>(begin: new Offset(0.0, 0.5), end: new Offset(0.0, 0.0)).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    ));
  }
```

In build method I called new object MaterialApp. Any idea why navigator not working?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already solved. its more likely about stack route.

because i build non linear navigator apps, so i reconfigure every each parent page.
and it's work.